# How to insert attribute value that is the same with value right above element in XML using python parsing

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I've been using python to parse and modify XML with xml.etree.ElementTree module.

Is it possible to insert same attribute value to the next same level element ?

It's for a example XML below :

```
<Root>
    <AAA size="small">
        <BBB>1</BBB>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>   <---- this element has no attribute
        <CCC>*</CCC>
    </AAA>
        <BBB>1</BBB>
    <AAA size="big">
        <BBB>1</BBB>
        <CCC>*</CCC>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>   <---- this element has no attribute
        <BBB>1</BBB>  
    </AAA>
    <AAA>   <---- this element has no attribute
        <CCC>1</CCC>  
    </AAA>
</Root>
```

I want to insert same attribute value to next same element like follow.

```
<Root>
    <AAA size="small">
        <BBB>1</BBB>
    </AAA>
    <AAA size="small">   <---- insert same attribute following AAA right above
        <CCC>*</CCC>
    </AAA>
        <BBB>1</BBB>
    <AAA size="big">   
        <BBB>1</BBB>
        <CCC>*</CCC>
    </AAA>
    <AAA size="big">   <---- insert same attribute following AAA right
        <BBB>1</BBB>  
    </AAA>
    <AAA size="big">   <---- insert same attribute following AAA right
        <CCC>1</CCC>  
    </AAA>
</Root>
```

So, i wonder if it is possible to make this using python.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()

previousAttr = ""
for child in root:
    if child.attrib:
        previousAttr = child.attrib         #Get Previous Attribute.
    else:
        for k,v in previousAttr.items():
            child.set(k, v)                  #Update Attribute.

tree.write(open(filename1, 'wb'))
```

Comment: Rakesh! Works very well. That a perfect! I spent whole day on thinking this  code. you made my day Thank you.